# Phonegap + Facebook plugin with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, angularjs, cordova

I want to develop an app in Javascript and deploy it using Phonegap on Android and iOS.
I want to use Facebook to log into my app.

So, I check out the phonegap-facebook plugin and everything worked fine (I managed to log in using FB). The problem is when I want to "angularize" the example code supplied with the plugin : in the index.html i have JS embed like this :

```
<script>
  // Initialize the Facebook SDK
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: 'XXX',
          nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
          useCachedDialogs: false
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);

      authUser();
      updateAuthElements();
  });
</script>
```

The js method called update the display directly (using document.getElementById).
I want to create a binding between my index.html and the javascript code in order to print facebook token and names using something like

```
{{user.token}} and {{user.names}}
```

Does someone managed to realize something like that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look here: https://gist.github.com/ruiwen/4722499

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's still looking to do the same thing, I spent a long time battling with this and eventually wrote a [fairly long blog post](http://noellh.com/blog/phonegap-angularjs-facebook/) detailing how I got it working.

I tried many existing suggestions including the Gist in subZero's comment above, but couldn't get it working with my Phonegap project on a device emulator.

My post walks through bootstrapping a fresh project using Phonegap + FB plugin + AngularJS, but for me the key missing piece to doing this straightforwardly and the 'Angular way' was the [angular-easyfb](https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb) module, which I believe only added Phonegap support recently. Well worth a look if you're stuck with this!

My demo app code using this module is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/NoelLH/4c1e79b8c24cb90757a1).

Comment: Just a quick note that while this still works generally in PG + AngularJS, it no longer works with [this Phonegap plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) & native mobile FB dialogs, past version 0.4.0, as they've abandoned parity with the FB JS SDK. I've explained and moaned about this [here](http://noellh.com/blog/facebook-cordova-angularjs-easyfb/) but haven't yet found an Angular module replacement for the newer versions of that PG plugin.

Comment: Well, only with the 2 native Phonegap plugins I mentioned in my post. If somebody made a JS-SDK-compatible plugin presumably it would work with native again. It still works fine independently of PG for making Facebook fit well into Angular, which is the main point of the module. The native support was a recent bonus that's been promptly broken by the PG plugin changing.

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
angular.element('[ng-controller=<name of the controller>]').scope().user = {token: <the extracted token>, names: <the extracted names>}
```